# Code disappearing in code indenting

Tags: bug

I've [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44436427/edit) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436427/the-character-hexadecimal-value-0x29-cannot-be-included-in-a-name/44436997) and noticed a strange issue.

Whenever I indent `<Formula>` to 4 spaces, it shows as code but in this specific answer the indent needs 4 spaces in each element but when I add that the code disappears in the question and not in the edit. It however needs 8 spaces (4 for the code tag, and 4 for the inner element) for the code to function.

I presume this is a bug of some sort, I've tested it in 2 browsers, vivaldi and chromium. However both use the blink engine.

I've uploaded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2L6ZPKTQ4U) of the issue I'm experiencing and the only character I've typed is a `space` and `?`.

Comment: There are tabs in that question, not spaces.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Delete the whitespace before `<Formula>` till `>`, enter it for a new line, now add 6 or 8 spaces. It disappears for me *after* the 4th space.

Comment: I edited the question to use only spaces and everything's visible.